# Only allowing a string/integer no decimals

Tags: python, validation

How would I go about:

1. Only allowing a string/integer input
2. Not allowing decimals

Answer (score 2):

cast to int and test str.isalpha:

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input() # input() python3
    try:
        inp = int(inp)
        break
    except ValueError:
        if inp.isalpha():
            break
        print("Invalid input")
```

If you actually want two different variables:

```
def get_name():
    while True:
        name = input("Enter your name: ")
        if name.isalpha():
            return name
        print("Invalid input")

def get_age():
    while True:
        age = input("Enter your age")
        try:
            return int(age)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input")


name = get_name()
age = get_age()
```

Comment: I'm using the newer version of python. How would I do this there?

Comment: @Vlad_Venger, just change raw_input to input

Comment: where would I add my variable here?  E.g name = str(input("What is your name?"))                 so that it only allows a string input

Comment: @Vlad_Venger, where is the variable coming from, are you taking input?

Comment: @Vlad_Venger,  `inp = input("What is your name?")` but if you want to test two different inputs then check `name =input("What is your name?");if name.isalpha()...` then whatever can only be an int try casting as above

Comment: while True:
    inp = input("What is your name?")# input() python3
    try:
        inp = int(inp)
        break
    except ValueError:
        if inp.isalpha():
            break
        print("Invalid input")         nothing happens when I run it. (apart from question)

Comment: I will edit, if you want to get two variables one for name that is only ascii and one that does not include decimals then take two separate inputs

Answer (score 0):

Use [isalnum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) built-in function.

```
>>> s = 'a'
>>> s.isalnum()
True
>>> s = '12'
>>> s.isalnum()
True
>>> s = '12.34'
>>> s.isalnum()
False
>>> s = 'ab12'
>>> s.isalnum()
True
```

Comment: what about negative numbers?